# How to enable json extension for PHP for cent OS

Tags: php, centos

i am new to cent  OS. followed [this tutorial](http://www.arckid.com/blog/amfphp/how-to-add-install-json-support-to-php-on-centos-in-10-steps/) but still unable to get the job done. its still showing that my script needs JSON extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. hopefully this will work.

```
You have to install:
* php-pear
* php-devel
* gcc
* make
```

THEN it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

The Tutorial is good.

you can check wheather the extension is installed when you go to your extension directory "/etc/php.d" there should be the **json.ini** if the extension is installed.

Open the **json.ini** and look wheather the line **"extension=json.so"** is without **#**.

When everything is correct the extension should be enabled.

Last step is to restart your http. Sometimes its possible that you have to stop and start the service.

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

You can test it with these lines. if its not working post the error message here.